Graph Api Access denied Calendar
I have a problem, I need to create an event in the calendar and it does not work. I get that I do not have access denied, check your credentials and try again.
I made a class for them to authenticate and get the token but I think it is not working well.
I don't want to use client secret.
Program
// Register GraphApplicationClientService
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GraphApplicationClientService>();

 public class GraphApplicationClientService
 {
     private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
     private readonly IHostEnvironment _environment;
     private GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

     public GraphApplicationClientService(IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment environment)
     {
         _configuration = configuration;
         _environment = environment;
     }

     public GraphServiceClient GetGraphClientWithManagedIdentityOrDevClient()
     {
         if (_graphServiceClient == null)
         {
             var scopes = new[]
             {
                 "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
             };

             var chainedTokenCredential = GetChainedTokenCredentials();
             _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(chainedTokenCredential, scopes);
         }

         return _graphServiceClient;
     }

     private ChainedTokenCredential GetChainedTokenCredentials()
     {

         var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
         {
             AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
         };

         var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

         return new ChainedTokenCredential(interactiveCredential);
     }
 }

private readonly GraphApplicationClientService _graphService;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, GraphApplicationClientService graphService)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _graphService = graphService;
}


 public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
 {
     var newEvent = new Event
     {
         Subject = "Let's go for lunch",
         Body = new ItemBody
         {
             ContentType = BodyType.Html,
             Content = "Does mid month work for you?",
         },
         Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
         {
             DateTime = "2019-03-15T12:00:00",
             TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
         },
         End = new DateTimeTimeZone
         {
             DateTime = "2019-03-15T14:00:00",
             TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
         },
         Location = new Location
         {
             DisplayName = "Harry's Bar",
         },
         Attendees = new List<Attendee>
         {
             new Attendee
             {
                 EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                 {
                     Address = "adelev@contoso.com",
                     Name = "Adele Vance",
                 },
                 Type = AttendeeType.Required,
             },
         },
         TransactionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
     };

     try
     {
         
         var graphClient = _graphService.GetGraphClientWithManagedIdentityOrDevClient();

         await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events.PostAsync(newEvent);

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError("", $"Error al agregar el evento: {ex.Message}");
         return View();
     }
 }

I have all the permissions you need to do this action.
enter image description here

Have you added the delegated permissions in the Azure AD?
